# Finding the highest value of object's field with specified _id in array of objects in mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, collections, max, database

I am new to mongodb. I am doing simple application that uses this database. Here is my doctors collection structure:

```
{
    _id: 1,
    name: "David",
    specialisation: "dentist",
    description: "Super dentist",
    treatments: [
        {
            _id: 0,
            price: 2200
        },
        {
            _id: 2,
            price: 200
        },
        {
            _id: 5,
            price: 2500
        },
        {
            _id: 8,
            price: 3200
        },
        {
            _id: 13,
            price: 2050
        }
    ],
    hospitals: [1, 2, 8, 5, 20]
},
{
    _id: 2,
    name: "John",
    specialisation: "dentist",
    description: "Super dentist",
    treatments: [
        {
            _id: 2,
            price: 2500
        }
    ],
    hospitals: [1]
}
```

What I want to do, is to get the max value of a treatment with specified id of all doctors in collection. For example in this case if I want to check treatment with _id = 2 it should return 2500, as it is written in John's object.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: In this structure u have to traverse treatments array then do find _id:2 , then keep max price field,then same process for next object and compare max price , this kinda approach vl work but however this seems inefficient structure, how about this `treatments:{1:"2200",2:"200",5:"2500",8:"3200",13:"2050"}` then u vl be able to do like treatments[2] or `treatments:{1:{key1:val1,key2:val2},2:{key1:val1,key2:val2}}`  tell which approach suits you , vl help u out in that approach's code

Comment: Unfortunatelly I have to keep this structure. I'm not sure what u mean by 'vl'.

Comment: sorry my bad , vl->will

Comment: ahh, ok. I've googled it so far and didn't found any interesting info :D

Comment: one doubt `treatment with _id = 2 it should return 2500, as it is written in John's object` here _id=2 u mean outside _id(above name:"john") or the one inside array ?

Comment: Inside one. It's the id of a treatment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94495/discussion-between-aishwat-singh-and-kuba12).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Named ur collection as `stack`
try this

```
db.stack.aggregate([ {$project:{"treatments._id":1, "treatments.price":1}}, 
{$unwind:"$treatments"},{$match:{"treatments._id":2}},
{$sort:{"treatments.price":-1}}, {$limit:1} ]);
```

result: `{ "_id" : 2, "treatments" : { "_id" : 2, "price" : 2500 } }`

ref: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/